# rails3: render :json can't be read from jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have two rails applications. In the first application
i have the following method in my controller:

```
def delivery_status
  envelope_id = params[:id]
  render :json => envelope.to_json(:include => [:deliveries, :log_lines])
end
```

which, if go to the url in my browser, nicely shows my the JSON. Seems ok.
However, if i call this through jQuery, from my second application, using the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#provisioning_sms_details_dialog').hide();

  $('.get_sms_details').live('click', function(event) {
      var el = $(this),
          data_url = el.attr('data-url');
      $.ajax({
        url: data_url,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data, status, req) {
          alert('received with status' + status)
          alert('received json ' + data);
        }
      });
  });
});
```

then the right url is hit with the correct parameters but `data` is always empty.
I first tried using `$.getJSON`, then`$.get` to end at `$.ajax`. I am not sure but it seems i am doing something wrong at server-side.
If i look at the request inside firebug, the response is indeed empty. Yet, i do not understand, if let the browser hit the same url, i get my json object.

Any insights how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a cross domain request? In that case your ajax-request would be of type HEAD, and you would only see an empty body. Ajax calls are restricted by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

If that is the case, you could look into using [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/), which would solve the problem.